# Are all Vedas and Puranas written by humans only?

Tags: vedas, puranas

I don't know about writers of all puranas or vedas but when ever I hear about a writer of any purana or veda then it's always a human. Are only humans allowed to write puranas and vedas? Is this a rule, a coincidence or anything else?

There are many more yonies like Deva yoni, Yaksha, Naag, Rakshas (there were some great rakshas also) and many more whose name I don't remember right now. Why they(people of any other yonies or lokas) didn't write any Vedas/Puranas? Does that mean, devotion can be found in humans the most? Or there is another reason? Or may be they have written but I am not aware of it.

The only non-human example I know is Ravana. I heard he is the one who write all vedas in form of music or song/poem, so that people can (kind of) sing shlokas and that will be helpful for people to easily grab knowledge because when we learn something in musical form then we understand much easily and early.

But Ravana did not write all vedas by himself. Vedas already were written, he only translate them in musical form on request of Lord Shiva (that's what I heard).

Comment: @Pandya None of your mentioned question has answered that Why any non-human didn't write Vedas/Puranas!! Then how it's duplicate? Please read whole description of question also, not just title. My raised point is totally different than your mentioned questions.

Comment: By non-humans u meant whom? which beings? Vedas were revealed to various Rishis. And the Puranas are also composed/compiled by one Rishi.

Comment: @Rickross Already described that in my question. Please read description of my question and you will get the answer :)

Comment: @Rishabh Please read answers of that questions. All your points are answered there.

Comment: @TheDestroyer All 7 anwers didn't mentioned anything about writers much. I heard story that one asura stole one veda and destroyed it. He got killed later but Shiva gave him boon that he will write that veda in his next birth. And he wrote it in his next birth. That vedas describes about health in brief. He was writer of one veda(dont remember name right now). One of the answered also said Vyasa write puranas. So always a human writers. This is my question, why only humans (rishi) writes about purana and vedas. I heard about writers but ur mentioened post is not describing it.

Comment: @Rishabh Oh my bad.. as usual i did not read through a long post thoroughly :(. Ok so why not Deva, Naga and other Yonis? We are talking about scriptures that are available to us (humans). So, that's why may be human-rishis. There may be more and different scriptures available for the residents of the other lokas. In those cases compilers/composers will not be human-rishis of course. For, example we know that the Devas have separate Puranas with them. More Puranas are available with them than that is available with human beings.

Comment: BTW, Rishis and Humans are regarded as different as far as categories are concerned ( Devas, Rishis, Manes and Manushya-Humans).